# IDEA и каретка

Tags: intellij-idea

Не могу найти негде как переключать режим каретки.
То есть из обычного в | в заменяющий прямоугольник(не знаю как называется)
Подскажите!

Comment: клавиша insert, если это ноутбук и она есть только на numpad - не забыть поклацать num lock.

Comment: Ты мой герой! Спасибо!